# Evaluate before delay, or delay before evaluate?

Tags: verilog

I have a statement of Verilog

```
Q = @(posedge Clk) D;
```

If evaluate before delay, this statement is equivalent to

```
begin
  Temp = D;
  @(posedge Clk)
  Q = Temp;
end
```

If delay before evaluate, this statement is equivalent to

```
begin
  @(posedge Clk)
  Q = D;
end
```

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct. Assignments with intra-assignment timing controls evaluate the RHS, store the value in a temporary, then execute the delay, then finally commit the temporary value to the LHS.

The story is a little more subtle if the LHS involves evaluation, e.g. an array index. For a blocking assignment, the LHS evaluation occurs after the timing control. For a non-blocking assignment, the LHS evaluation occurs at the time the RHS is evaluated.

e.g.

```
reg [31:0] y, z;
integer i;

initial begin
   i = 0;
   y[i] = #10 1;   // y[3] affected, i evaluated at time 10
end
initial begin
   #1;
   z[i] <= #10 1;  // z[0] affected, i evaluated at time 1
end

initial #5 i = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Q = <delay_control> D;
```

is equivalent to

```
Q_tmp = D;
<delay_control>
Q = Q_tmp;
```

So your first example. I strongly suggest never ever using this syntax as it is very confusing when embedding inside a procedural block of code. Use a non-blocking assignment instead

```
Q <= @(posedge CLK) D;
```

Note that most synthesis tools do not accept this style of behavioral code.